# Finding the image of a homomorphism

Tags: group-theory

I'm struggling a bit with how to find the image of a  homomorphism. For instance, I'm given that

$$f:G\to G/H \text{ defined by } f(g)=gH \text{ is a homomorphism}$$

and I'm asked to prove that the image is $G/H$.

I know that the definition of an image is $\operatorname{im} f = \lbrace f(g) \mid g\in G\rbrace$ but I just can't work out how to get from one to the other. Any suggestions or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $G/H$ is a set of cosets, namely it is $\{gH, g\in G\}$. What you want to show is that $f$ is surjective, but this is straigthforward for if you take $gH \in G/H$, then $g$ is an antecedent.

Answer (score 2):

Every element in $G/H$ is of the form $gH$ for some $g\in G$ (by definition). Can you find an element of $G$ such that $f$ maps that element to $gH$? (Look at the definition of $f$ and the form of the element of $G/H$.) Then you will have shown that for any element of $G/H$, there is some $g\in G$ such that $f(g)$ is that element, which is exactly what it means for the image to be all of $G/H$ (equivalently, that $f$ is surjective).

Comment: Oh! I totally missed the link between images and $f$ being surjective. I think I've already shown that it's surjective elsewhere. Thanks so much for your help :-)